# How do I instrument `.vue` files using the istanbul/nyc command line

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, code-coverage, istanbul, nyc

Ultimately, I am trying to instrument my Vue 3 app so that I can get code coverage that includes my `.js` and `.vue` files using the below command:

```
nyc instrument --compact=false src instrumented
```

I see that my `.vue` files are getting duplicated and included in my `instrumented` folder thanks to my `.nycrc` configuration.

```
{
  "extension": [".js", ".vue"]
}
```

But they are not getting instrumented.

They are simply copies.

What else do I need to do to get these files properly instrumented so that they can be included in my coverage report?

Comment: I need to get coverage for Cypress e2e. So I’m forced to use Istanbul/nyc